# Error installing thingsboard community edition

Tags: thingsboard

I'm getting this error during the installation, i tried using docker this time and i'm getting the same error over and over, i trying on a ubuntu 18 instance (openstack) and i can't find a solution. I followed the documentation ( i tried on a AWS EC2 instance and it work just fine). Please any help !

> Error creating bean with name 'thingsboardInstallService': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'entityDatabaseSchemaService';
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'psqlEntityDatabaseSchemaService':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'installScripts';
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'installScripts': Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through field 'ruleChainService'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'baseRuleChainService': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'relationService'; nested exception
> is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'baseRelationService': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'entityService'; nested exception
> is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'baseEntityService': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'assetService'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'baseAssetService': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'assetDao'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'jpaAssetDao': Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through field 'assetRepository'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'assetRepository' defined in
> org.thingsboard.server.dao.sql.asset.AssetRepository defined in
> @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaDaoConfig: Invocation of init
> method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> Using named parameters for method public abstract
> org.springframework.data.domain.Page
> org.thingsboard.server.dao.sql.asset.AssetRepository.findAssetInfosByTenantId(java.util.UUID,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)
> but parameter 'Optional[tenantId]' not found in annotated query
> 'SELECT new org.thingsboard.server.dao.model.sql.AssetInfoEntity(a,
> c.title, c.additionalInfo) FROM AssetEntity a LEFT JOIN CustomerEntity
> c on c.id = a.customerId WHERE a.tenantId = :tenantId AND
> LOWER(a.searchText) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT(:textSearch, '%'))'!

[The error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfSLu.png)

**Environment**

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS on Openstack

ThingsBoard: 3.2.1